# When does OneNote delete its page history?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

When I show the page history for a page in my OneNote notebook, I see the following information bar above old versions:

[image: It will be deleted over time, says OneNote]

This worries me; specifically the bit that says "It will be deleted over time". **When** exactly is it deleted? And can I set something in OneNote to preserve the page history forever? I don't ever want to lose it. :(

Thanks.